# preg_match_all - parse simple code

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have problem with parse text into array

My regex:

```
/\s*DEF\s+FUNC\s+(\w+\d*)\((\w*[.\s\w]*|)\)\s*{\s*(.*)\s*}/s
```

My text:

```
DEF FUNC test(param) 
{
    test1;
};

DEF FUNC testSecond() 
{
    test1
    test1
};
```

It should return array like:

```
(
[0] => DEF FUNC test(param) 
       {
          test1;
       };

[1] => DEF FUNC testSecond() 
       {
          test1
          test1
       };  
)
```

but now I have only one element in array:

```
(
[0] => DEF FUNC test(param) 
       {
          test1;
       };

       DEF FUNC testSecond() 
       {
          test1
          test1
       };  
)
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: You need to implement a *real parser* for that.

Comment: Its little simple thing. I don't create new language ;)

Comment: Regex doesn't count, so there's no way you'd be able to put an incrementing number in front of an arbitrary number of matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `*` quantifier lazy with `?`: `(.*?)`.

Also your regex can be simplified, `(\w*[.\s\w]*|)` is the same as `([.\s\w]*)` (and the `.` here stands for a dot, not any character):

```
/\s*DEF\s+FUNC\s+(\w+\d*)\([.\s\w]*\)\s*{\s*(.*?)\s*}/s
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of greediness. The `.*` inside the block will read as much of anything, as it possibly can, which means that the last `}` will be the last one in the text.

To make it non-greedy you can put a question mark after the `*` quantifier.

```
/DEF\s+FUNC\s+(?:\w+\d*)\([.\s\w]*\)\s*{.*?}/s
```

I have also simplified the regex as follows:

- Made a capturing group non-capturing, and removed unnecessary group
- The leading white-space does not seem to be necessary
- The `(\w*[.\s\w]*|)` is the same as `[.\s\w]*`
- And inside the block, `.*` already takes care of the surrounding white-space

Finally, this regex is not very reliable. If there is a closing curly brace, `}`, somewhere inside the block of the `DEF` then it will screw everything up. There is no way to do this properly using regular expressions.

If you are really serious about this then writing a little parser may be the way to go.